# PhysicsJs - how to remove a world behavior, "constant-acceration' after it has been added

Tags: javascript, physicsjs

My behaviors on initialization are added as follows:

```
world.add([
    Physics.behavior('interactive', { el: renderer.el }),
     Physics.behavior('constant-acceleration'),
    Physics.behavior('body-impulse-response'),
    Physics.behavior('sweep-prune'),
    edgeBounce
]);
```

I'd like to, at a later time, remove the "constant-acceleration" behavior.  I read a couple of posts that said to use the remove() method but I'm not getting anything to happen using it like follows:

```
world.remove( Physics.behavior('constant-acceleration') );
```

Can anyone advise how I could achieve removing a specific behavior from the world after it has been added?

Comment: I don't have any PhysicsJS experience, but the [`Physics.behavior`](http://bit.ly/1G0cBqX) docs indicate that a `Behavior` object is returned when you call `Physics.behavior` (because it constructs a new one). So you need to keep a reference to the `Behavior` object you'd get back from the call you've put into your `world.add` array, then pass that reference to [`world.remove`](http://bit.ly/12sjySu) later. As it is now, you're making a new `Behavior` (separate from the one you made first) and immediately passing that brand new object to `world.remove`, which will basically do nothing.

Comment: That was it!  thanks!  If you convert you comment to an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Done! Glad that's what it was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`Physics.behavior`](http://bit.ly/1G0cBqX) docs indicate that a `Behavior` object is returned when you call `Physics.behavior` (because it constructs a new one). So you need to keep a reference to the `Behavior` object you'd get back from the call you've put into your `world.add` array, then pass that reference to [`world.remove`](http://bit.ly/12sjySu) later. As it is now, you're making a new `Behavior` (separate from the one you made first) and immediately passing that brand new object to `world.remove`, which will basically do nothing.